# xpath syntax meaning

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to understand a piece of code I should manage. I found some html manipulation in which HtmlAgilityPack is used for some node selection. Someone knows the meaning of this xpath selector?

```
//table/*[not(self::tr or self::tbody)]
```

Comment: Which part(s) do you not understand?

Comment: What kind of elements I'm expecting? In the form of "For each table, all the child elements that verify [the condition]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English:

> Select any element node (`*`) *such that* it is not itself a `tr` or
>   `tbody` (`[not(self::tr or self::tbody)]`) and that is the child of a
>   `table` element that could appear anywhere in the document (`//table`).

It is equivalent to the following un-abbreviated expression

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::table/child::*[not(self::tr or self::tbody)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`self` is a handy way of referring to the name of the element node under consideration, without namespaces.

In this example, we will match *any* element which is a child of a `table`, and is *not* a `tr` or a `tbody`.